# python Selenium, signing into twitter

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to log into twitter to access direct messages. And I need to automate the process using selenium. To do this I have to log in to twitter and authorize my app.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
# Selenium opens up webpage
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login?input_flow_data=%7B%22requested_variant%22%3A%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%3D%22%7D")
username_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "text")
username_input.send_keys('send username here')
```

This code is opening the site and then I am trying to enter the username however I get an error that says no such element is found. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it doesn't seem like you are waiting for the page to load  after get() try adding a `time.sleep(5)` or such to wait for the page to load before trying to send_keys()

Comment: Your code is working fine, you just need to add some wait time:   'driver.implicitly_wait(15)'

Answer (score 0):

May you need a bit `wait`:

```
username_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'text')))
username_input.send_keys('send username here')
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```